# Hide all images inside DIV except one without scrollbars

Tags: asp.net, css, image, html, hide

I have a div container where I am displaying multiple images and now I need to display only one image and hide the rest of the images.

So how do I do that?

Here is my container:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
    $(function () {
        $("#uploader").plupload({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
            url: 'Final.aspx',
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            max_file_count: 25,
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,

            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            //                    resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [
        { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
        { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
    ],

            // thumbnails
            thumb: { width: 100, height: 100, quality: 90 },

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload.flash.swf',

            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
        });


        // Client side form validation
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

            // Files in queue upload them first
            if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                // When all files are uploaded submit form
                uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                    if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                        $('form')[0].submit();
                    }
                });

                uploader.start();
            }
            else
                alert('You must at least upload one file.');

            return false;
        });
        var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
        uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {

            $('#showfilelist').append("<div id=" + file.id + " class='thumb'><a href='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' target='_blank' rel='gallery'><img src='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='50' height='50'/></a></div>");

        });    
    });
```

Comment: How do you determine which image to be showed? By ID?

Comment: I need the first or last image from the uploads.And If I take another div to be displayed it is appending to one another.So I want to hide except one.And If I use append I get this problem and Iam not sure how to use for Asp.Net Image control to display it's URL.

Comment: You say you're using asp.net. Is there a reason you can't control which images are displayed on the server side? If not, as long as each image has a unique class or ID that you know at runtime, you can hide/show with JQuery as in my answer below.

Comment: Yes there is a reason as soon as the user uploads the images all will be uploaded to the div container and suppose if he clicks on the image then the image should be able to display in the image control.If I use append as shown above all the images are displaying even in the image control So I need to show the first uploaded image or the last image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like:

`$('#showfilelist div').hide(); // Hide all appended divs`
`$('#showfilelist div').eq(0).show(); // Show the first one`

Comment: The same nothing is displaying all are hiding.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be $('#showfilelist div:eq(0)').show(); ? Otherwise, you're just matching the container div.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
$(".thumb").hide();
$("#" + file.id).show();
```

(Where file.id is the id of the one image you want to be visible.)

If you just want to show the first thumb, do this:

```
$(".thumb").hide();
$(".thumb:first").show();
```

To show the last thumb, just use the ":last" selector instead of ":first".

Comment: Now nothing is displaying!Even the thumbnails.

Comment: Be sure file.id is set to the correct value before calling that 2nd line. The first line hides all of the thumbs. The 2nd line shows only the one you want visible.

Comment: There is nothing to set with the id as it is predefined with the plupload.js script